# Help us fix this sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.UserID, UserLastName, UserFirstName, UserName, Notified, 
MAX (CycleNumber) as CycleNumber, (CycleCurrentStep) as CycleCurrentStep, 
MAX (CycleDateReported) as CycleDateReported, 
max (cycleid)
FROM [User] u 
left join Cycle c on (u.UserID = c.UserID) 
join UserDivSection us on (u.UserID = us.UserID 
and us.DivSectionID=26) 
group by u.UserID, UserLastName, UserFirstName, UserName, Notified, c.CycleCurrentStep
```

```
UserID  UserLastName    UserFirstName   UserName    Notified    CycleNumber CycleCurrentStep    CycleDateReported   
290 Williams    Craig   craasdf@gmail.com   1   7   0       208
290 Williams    Craig   craasdf@gmail.com   1   9   3       210
290 Williams    Craig   craasdf@gmail.com   1   7   5   1/29/2010 3:06:23 PM    204
290 Williams    Craig   craasdf@gmail.com   1   8   6   2/1/2010 9:26:40 AM 209
```

We're trying to return rows with unique non-repeating userids matching with the max cyclenumber for that userid. Right now the query is returning the same userid multiple times for various cyclenumbers. We're not exactly sure how to proceed with the correct query. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a MAX missing before `(CycleCurrentStep)`?

Comment: basically what you need to do is run a query that gets the max(CycleNumber) for each user and then join into that to get the rest of the data about that particular User/CycleNumber combination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with a subquery in your where clause. Something like:

```
SELECT u.UserID, UserLastName, UserFirstName, UserName, Notified, 
CycleNumber, CycleCurrentStep, CycleDateReported, cycleid
FROM [User] u 
left join Cycle c on (u.UserID = c.UserID) 
join UserDivSection us on (u.UserID = us.UserID and us.DivSectionID=26) 
where cyclenumber = ( select max(cyclenumber) from cycle where cycle.userid = u.userid)
```

I'm not sure about the UserDivSection part though.

Answer (score 2):

Remove CycleCurrentStep from your group by clause.

Answer (score 1):

Ths is probably because you group by on `c.CycleCurrentStep`. This is an unaggregated column from Cycle - if there happen to be more than one distinct value of `CycleCurrentStep` for all rows in `Cycle` corresponding to one row from `User`, then you will get just as many rows for that user in the result as there are distinct values for `CycleCurrentStep`

You can remove the  `CycleCurrentStep` column from your `GROUP BY` list,  but then you will have to remove it also from the `SELECT` list - that's because you cannot at the same time aggregate all corresponding `Cycle` rows as a group and then pick an unaggreagated value and report it. So if you remove `CycleCurrentStep` from the `GROUP BY` you must either remove it from the `SELECT` list too, or apply a meaningful aggreagate function to it, just like you did with the other columns from `Cycle` where you applied the `MAX()` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    u.UserID, 
    UserLastName, 
    UserFirstName, 
    UserName, 
    Notified, 
    c.CycleNumber, 
    c.CycleCurrentStep, 
    c.CycleDateReported, 
    c.cycleid
FROM
    [User] u 
    INNER JOIN 

    (SELECT 
        u.UserID
        Max(CycleNumber) CycleNumber,
    FROM 
        [User] u 
        left join Cycle c on (u.UserID = c.UserID) 
    GROUP BY
        u.UserID) MaxCycle
    ON u.UserID = MaxCycle.UserId
    INNER JOIN Cycle c
    ON MaxCycle.Cycleumber = c.CycleNumber
```